# closed surface integral in a vector field has non-zero value

Tags: multivariable-calculus, vector-analysis

Let's say i have a closed surface S, for instance the surface of a cube.

and I take the surface integral in a vector field $\vec{F}$ over this closed surface:

$$\oint \limits_S\vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} ~dS$$

I would expect that net flux going into the surface equals flux going out of the surface and the integral should be zero:

$$\oint \limits_S\vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} ~dS = 0$$

However, the example, i'm looking at in the book has this integral having a value that is non-zero.

Its this because the vector field $\vec{F}$ is non-conservative that causes the close surface integral to be non-zero?  That is: $\nabla \times \vec{F} = 0$.

---

The problem is rather lengthy, but I will put it here just so the question has context.

let $\vec{F} = 4zxz\hat{\text{i}} - y^2\hat{\text{j}} + yz\hat{\text{k}}$.  Evaluate $\oint \limits_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ dS$, where S is cube bounded by: x=0, x=1, y=0, y=1, z=0, z=1.

then its  matter of finding the surface integal of each of the  sides of the cube.

$\begin{aligned}\oint \limits_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds &= \int \limits_{\text{side 1}} \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds + \int \limits_{\text{side 2}} \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds \\ &+ \int \limits_{\text{side 3}} \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds + \int \limits_{\text{side 4}} \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds + \int \limits_{\text{side 5}} \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds + \int \limits_{\text{side 6}} \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds\end{aligned}$

$\oint \limits_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n}~ds = (2) + (0) + (-1) + (0) + (\frac{1}{2}) + (0) = \frac{3}{2}$

Comment: No.  The flux through every surface is 0 if and only the divergence (i.e. $\nabla \cdot F$) is zero.

Comment: ahh... ok...thanks.  I was just wondering because this book doesn't really talk about it...

Comment: That is the same as saying that there are no "sources" or "sinks" inside the surface.

Answer (score 1):

**solenoidal**: a vector field which has zero divergence everywhere is called solenoidal, and any closed surface in the vector field has no a net flux across it, that is: flux in = flux out.